# Bruteforce Tools for ZuluCrypt?

Tags: software-recommendation, encryption

I forgot my password on an encrypted file that's encrypted with ZuluCrypt. I think brute force is the only way to decrypt that file. I set the password after all so I have plenty of information about it, just that I forgot the exact details. Is there a tool that can help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are mildly proficient with shell scripting, then you could create something that uses [the zukuCrypt CLI](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/zuluCrypt-cli.1.html) and loops through possible passwords that you may have set.

For example, if you're using a common `phrase` + `number` password methodology, then could do something like:

```
zuluCrypt-cli -o -d /dev/sdXY -m private -e ro -p {passphrase}
```

If the passphrase is no good, then move on to the next possibility. I do not believe there is a lock-out mechanism in place for zuluCrypt when there are too many failed attempts, so this could be the way forward.